# getting checkBox element count

Tags: android, checkbox

Working with apis, I am uncertain of the number of checkBoxes that will appear in the application. How can get the count of the number of checkBoxes produced in the application ?
Also, these checkBoxes are declared inside a listView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop though all the child views in you layout and find out how many of them are checkboxes. Looping and checking is done in following way:

```
ll is LinearLayout here

int childcount = ll.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
      View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
      if (view instanceof CheckBox) {
           count++;
      }
}
```

Comment: so if i am working with a listView ... should i use the listView instead of the linearn layout ?